# The divisor map is injective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have finished Vakil's FOAG and am reviewing some concepts. I realized I left a gaping hole in my understanding when it comes to Proposition 14.2.1. The goal is to show

$$\operatorname{div}: \{(\mathcal L, s)\}/\text{isomorphism} \to \operatorname{Weil}(X)$$

sending $s$ to its divisor is an isomorphism for Noetherian normal schemes $X$, where $\mathcal L$ is an invertible sheaf and $s$ is a nonzero rational section. The first line in the proof claims that if $\operatorname{div} s = 0$, then $s$ cannot have any poles. Why? What about the function $s = x^3/(x + 1)^3$, a slight tweak to Vakil's 14.2 A a) example?

Comment: For your section, $\operatorname{div} s = 3[0] - 3[-1]$, not $0$.

Comment: And I just realized my issue is that I am mixing up degree with the divisor itself. Thank you!